# Handle Javascript file download in iOS Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, canvas

I have tried many ways over given in the SO to handle the download file path coming through javascript. But I am unable to get the path(URL) of the file.

In ANDROID we have **[DownloadListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/DownloadListener.html)** method of Android WebKit. By which I managed to get the URL of the file.

**What I have tried:**

With **decidePolicyForNavigationResponse** and **decidePolicyForNavigationAction** i am not getting any url of the file.
For the information, In the website URL they use [CANVAS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). After click on the download button, they generate a BLOB image path to download it on the client end.

It is also by default working with the GOOGLE CHROME browser in iPad but doesn't work with the SAFARI browser.

Also, javascript is enabled. So it is not creating an issue.

**EDIT:**

For testing purposes use this [link](http://fancyproductdesigner.com/product/t-shirt/), On click of the download button, they trigger an event

**EDIT 2**

I checked in the website by doing some debugging that they are using **window.open** with **target="_blank"** for the new image path. After window.open they are setting **window.location.href = popup.document** in which **popup** is a instance of **window.open**

In WKWebView they have disabled the popup window as they blocked it. But I am now wondering how GOOGLE CHROME manages it as they are on WKWebView based too.

Comment: updated as requested @Cristik

Comment: I don't see any code in the question. Please add the relevant code **in the question**.

Comment: I am just using **WKWebView** with javascript enabled in it

Comment: You mention at least two pieces of code: javascript downloading files and Swift trying to intercept the download. None of these is present in the question, you only describe them

Comment: @RahulKhurana If Google Chrome can manage it, you can checkout Chromium code and check it yourself https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Comment: @RahulKhurana are you actually targeting that website or another one? Also is it yours? meaning do you have access to the JavaScript too?

Comment: No, i have included the same functionality on my website. And yes i have access to the javascript. If you help me with downloading file with Wkwebview it would be great help.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial

Comment: this actually worked for me.  https://github.com/WildDylan/WKWebViewWithURLProtocol

Comment: I downloaded your code and try replacing hardcoded url with the link given in question. But it is not even nearby the thing i am trying to acheive

Answer (score 1):

In your given link the image is generated dynamically and is at some point available as `<a href='data:image/png;base64,iVB...'`. One can also see, that jQuery is used there.

I also assume that the download should work with desktop browsers.

One solution could be to inject JavaScript code into your app that adds a click handler for the dynamically created `a` tag and transfers the `href` base64 encoded image data to the app.

There the image can be decoded and processed further.

**Swift 4:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: self.config())
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let url = URL(string: httpAddress) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }

    private func config() -> WKWebViewConfiguration {
        let scriptName = "GetDownloadData"
        let javaScript = "$('body').on('click', 'a.download-anchor', function(e) {"
                    +    "    webkit.messageHandlers.\(scriptName).postMessage('clicked ' + e.target.href); "
                    +    "}); "
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: javaScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: scriptName)
        return config
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("message: \(message.name) \(message.body)")
    }
}
```

To mimic the dynamic JavaScript image creation and make it available in the `href` property of the `a` tag, here a small server-side example:

```
<html>
<head><title>dynamic download</title>
<head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button id='download'>download</button>

    <div id='area'></div>    

<script>        
    $("#download").on("click", function(){
        $("#area").append("<a href='data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAMAAABEpIrGAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAYUExURf////8PD//39/8WFv+7u/9SUv9ZWf/Kyvchv38AAAB0SURBVDjLfcrHAcAwDMNAucX7b5zEXTJFfA8iuhqFllOJ3ENgx+/s6O4f071jOz5OR4f2+7Buj9v1gfw8sO/D83n43o9KPIRHJBbiKQs9mpNjuHssd47D4aEcHMav43JzAFcH9ONwfB2uj4N4O6h/x8Md9ALiMQNEcD5b+AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' download='Product.png' target='_blank' class='download-anchor' style='display: none;'></a>").find('a')[0].click()
    });

</script>       

</body>
</html>
```

The Swift code above with this HTML/JavaScript server side file prints out the following in Xcode's console:

```
message: GetDownloadData clicked data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0...
```

So mission accomplished: the image is available on app side. Also the image can still be downloaded in desktop browsers.

Instead of `data:image/png` I've chosen `data:application/octet-stream` since some desktop browser otherwise would try to show the image in a separate browser tab instead of downloading it.

Comment: I have already explained in the question that they are using CANVAS and not using any image

Comment: Sry, misunderstood the requirements. You mentioned in comments that you try to achieve something similar then by the provided link and you _have access to the javascript_.  My answer contains a very simplified self-containing solution. By taking a look in Chrome in the DOM tree after pressing the download button in your provided link you can see such a dynamically created `a` tag with the data that is afterwards downloaded. Like mentioned in other comments it might be helpful to narrow down the question more precisely, e.g. by providing some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to javascript code, you can use `WKScriptMessageHandler`:

```
class JavascriptMessageHandler:NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        guard let base64ImageString = message.body as? String else {
            // No image data, handle error
            return
        }
        guard let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64ImageString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
            // String can't be decoded to data
            return
        }
        let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
        // Do whatever with decoded image
    }
}

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(JavascriptMessageHandler(), name: "imageBlobDownload")

config.userContentController = contentController
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

If you just want to download image as file, there's no need to convert to UIImage, you can just save Data.

And call this code from javascript like this:

```
try {
    webkit.messageHandlers.imageBlobDownload.postMessage("base64image");
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Not iOS app');
}
```

Note that "base64image" is *only* base64 data without any prefixes.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. But this didn't help either

Comment: @RahulKhurana did you initialize WKWebView as above?

Comment: Does the userContentController method run?

Comment: i know how the `WKScriptMessageHandler ` works.. i.e. how to send callback to Swift/C from Javascript

Comment: So, where does this break?

Comment: have you given a try with link provided in the question?

Comment: It can't work without access to javascript... You do have access to javascript code?

Comment: if it is working with GOOGLE CHROME there must be a way to support with WKWebview without javascript changes